# Pyautogui проверка картинки в цикле

Tags: python, python-3.x, while, pyautogui

Есть задача, у меня есть картинка, она появляется в определенный момент, то есть изначально её нет. 
Решил через цикл постоянно искать эту картинку.

Написал такой код:

```
import pyautogui
import time

while pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(r'D:\Bot.py\pythonProject2\screen\image.png', confidence=0.5) is not None:

    print("None")
    time.sleep(5)

a = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(r"D:\Bot.py\pythonProject2\screen\image.png")

print(a)

pyautogui.moveTo(a)

pyautogui.click()
```

При запуске кода получаю:

[image: прикол]

Что делать как быть?

P.S. Ругается что картинка не найдена, но в этом и весь прикол, если картинка не найдена, код запускается заново, если найдено - выполняет тело кода.

Comment: Какое слово вам непонятно в тексте ошибки?

Comment: в принципе вся запись, он ругается что картинка не найдена, но в этом и весь прикол, если картинка не найдена, код запускается заново, если найдено - выполняет тело кода

Comment: В тексте ошибки нет ничего про ненайденную картинку. Вы вообще читали его?

Comment: Забавно, а я и не знал что в pyautogui завезли работу с OpenCV^^

Answer (score 2):

[**Документация pyautogui**](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html)

*Note: You need to have OpenCV installed for the confidence keyword to work.*

Перевод, кратко: **Вам необходимо установить OpenCV.** `pip install opencv-python`

```
import pyautogui
location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image.png')
# location возвращает кортеж (left=1416, top=562, width=50, height=41)
point = pyautogui.center(location)
# point получаем центр картинки которую нашли(координаты)

x, y = point
pyautogui.click(x, y)  # щелкает по центру того места, где была найдена картинка
pyautogui.click('image.png') # сокращенная версия для нажатия в центре того места, где была найдена картинка
```

*If the image can’t be found on the screen, locateOnScreen() raises ImageNotFoundException.*

Если изображение не удается найти на экране, метод locateOnScreen() вызывает исключение ImageNotFoundException. И если вы ищите картинку в цикле, вам нужно обрабатывать это исключение.

`confidence=0.5` как по мне маловато будет. Лучше устанавливать значение от `0.8`

По итогу я бы сделал что-то такое:

```
import pyautogui
from pyautogui import ImageNotFoundException
import time

while True:
    try:
        location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image.png', confidence=0.85)

        point = pyautogui.center(location)
        x, y = point
        pyautogui.click(x, y)
        break  # Выход из цикла после успешного клика
        
    except ImageNotFoundException:
        print("Изображение не найдено. Повторная попытка через секунду...")
        time.sleep(1)  # Пауза перед повторной попыткой
```