# {opencv} как сместить координаты мышки в выделенную область?

Tags: python, winapi, opencv, pywin32

При нахождении объекта на экране курсор должен на него наводиться, при полноэкранном разрешении все работает, но мне хочется оптимизировать бота и сузить область для поиска.
экран у меня обрезать получается, но вот мой курсор перемещается на сохраненные в переменной координаты от ширины всего экрана, а не области которая мне нужна, не знаю как правильно реализовать чтобы координаты отчитывались от нужной мне области и как ее выделить
надеюсь понятно сформулировал

Код

```
import time
import win32api, win32con
import os
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np
import cv2
from pprint import pformat

box = (289, 90,1067, 710)

img_hhh = cv2.imread('C:/jdws/Screenshot_1.png', 0)
def locate_image(template, threshold=0.8):
    screenshot = ImageGrab.grab(box)
    screenshot = np.array(screenshot)
    screenshot = cv2.cvtColor(screenshot, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    screenshot_gray = cv2.cvtColor(screenshot, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    
    result = cv2.matchTemplate(screenshot_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
    
    if max_val >= threshold:
        return (max_loc[0], max_loc[1])
    else:
        return None

while True:
    vosem_loc = locate_image(img_hhh)
    if vosem_loc:
        rock = print(vosem_loc)
        time.sleep(1)

        win32api.SetCursorPos(vosem_loc)
```

Update: Ещё мне в любом случае нужно будет от итоговых координат отсчитывать пиксели так что если кто-то поделится методом сложения буду благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Я делаю вот так:

```
import pyautogui
import cv2
import numpy as np
# Координаты для точки скриншота \ высота и ширина от точки координат 
x=289
y=90
width=1067
height=710

# Загрузка шаблона
template = cv2.imread(file_path)
                    
screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x, y, width, height))
screenshot = np.array(screenshot)
screenshot = cv2.cvtColor(screenshot, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
                    
# Поиск соответствия шаблона на скриншоте
result = cv2.matchTemplate(screenshot, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        
# Получение координат максимального значения соответствия
_, max_val, _, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

threshold = 0.8  # Пороговое значение (можно настроить)
if max_val >= threshold:                  
    h, w = template.shape[:2] # height, width шаблона
    # Вычисление координат центра совпадения
    center_x = (x + max_loc[0]) + w // 2
    center_y = (y + max_loc[1]) + h // 2
```

По итогу получаем абсолютные координаты шаблона на мониторе.

З.Ы. А если не сильно запариваться, то с OpenCV можно работать через [pyautogui](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1562106/562052)

Comment: это помоему не то что мне нужно,
я могу определить  и задать область своим кодом, а вот подвести курсор к нужному значению не выходит тк как полученные с переменной координаты верны только в выделенной области и она не распространяется на команду win32api.SetCursorPos() так как та принимает значение от всего экрана, а как выставить свое я не понимаю
в этом вся проблема

Comment: Моя реализация делает скриншот определенной области экрана. Далее я получаю координаты объекта относительно скриншота. Затем получаю координаты относительно экрана, зная координаты скриншота. win32api.SetCursorPos((center_x, center_y)) - по полученным координатам курсор нормально устанавливается‍♀️